# Selecting a name from another table using a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, select, foreign-keys

Im new to php and I found a small piece of code online which was almost perfect for what I wanted, however for three of the sections (function, manager & zone) it is displaying the ID instead of the name, which are held in other tables (functions, managers & zones) linked with the ID as the foreign key

functions (functionID, Functionname)
managers (managerID, Managername)
zones (zoneID, Zonename)

So I want the table to display the name instead of the id, if anyone could help I would very much appreciate it

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

</head>
<body >

<?
$con = mysql_connect ("localhost","xxx","xx");
if (!$con){
die("can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("xx",$con);

//////Displaying Data/////////////
$id=$_GET['requestID']; // Collecting data from query string
if(!is_numeric($id)){ // Checking data it is a number or not
echo "Data Error"; 
exit;
}

$q=mysql_query("select * from requests where requestID=$id ");
$row=mysql_fetch_object($q);
echo mysql_error();
echo "<table>";

echo "
<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><td><b>Function</b></td><td>$row->functionID</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Manager</b></td><td>$row->managerID</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><td><b>Zone</b></td><td>$row->zoneID</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Headcount Request</b></td><td>$row->Headcountrequest</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><td><b>Utilisation</b></td><td>$row->Utilisation</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Current Headcount</b></td><td>$row->Currentquarterheadcount</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><td><b>Entered By</b></td><td>$row->Enteredby</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Start Date<br>(YYYY-MM-DD)</b></td><td>$row->Startdate</td></tr>
 ";
echo "</table>";

//////////////////// 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$q=mysql_query("select * from requests where requestID=$id ");
```

to this:

```
$q=mysql_query("select r.*, f.Functionname,  m.Managername, z.Zonename from requests as r  inner join functions as f on r.functionID = f.functionID inner join managers as m on r.managerID = m.managerID inner join zones as z on r.zoneID = z.zoneID where r.requestID=$id ");
```

Then change:

```
echo "
<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><td><b>Function</b></td><td>$row->functionID</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Manager</b></td><td>$row->managerID</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><td><b>Zone</b></td><td>$row->zoneID</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Headcount Request</b></td><td>$row->Headcountrequest</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><td><b>Utilisation</b></td><td>$row->Utilisation</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Current Headcount</b></td><td>$row->Currentquarterheadcount</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><td><b>Entered By</b></td><td>$row->Enteredby</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Start Date<br>(YYYY-MM-DD)</b></td><td>$row->Startdate</td></tr>
 ";
```

to:

```
echo "
<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><td><b>Function</b></td><td>$row->Functionname</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Manager</b></td><td>$row->Managername</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><td><b>Zone</b></td><td>$row->Zonename</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Headcount Request</b></td><td>$row->Headcountrequest</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><td><b>Utilisation</b></td><td>$row->Utilisation</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Current Headcount</b></td><td>$row->Currentquarterheadcount</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><td><b>Entered By</b></td><td>$row->Enteredby</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Start Date<br>(YYYY-MM-DD)</b></td><td>$row->Startdate</td></tr>
 ";
```

Assuming I've typed all of that correctly you should now have a query that joins your 4 tables together using the *ID fields and selects the *name fields from each of the joined tables.  Not having access to your database and having not written SQL by hand in awhile this might not be exactly correct, but should put you on the right path.

Comment: Glad to help.  Even though it's the only answer you should mark it as accepted so others will see the nice green checkmark and know it worked for you.